# Node.js: how to inspect errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I am quite puzzled by Node.js `Error` object, when logged to console...
As an example, I have this code:

```
request(
  options,
  function (err, response, contents) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error in request:', err);
    }
    success(contents);
  },
);
```

Sometimes it errors out for an `ECONNRESET` error... So far so good.
The `console.error()` (or `console.log()`) format  is this:

```
[Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET'
```

I cannot understand the format printed: why "Error: socket hang up" is among square brackets? Is it an object?
One for all: how can I inspect error object so I can see all individual properties?

**UPDATE:**
Following *@chriskelly* answer, after running node in debug mode, I get:

```
debug> repl
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
> typeof err
'object'
> Object.keys(err)
[]
> console.dir(err)
< [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET'
```

I keep not understanding `err` object: no keys, but is has content... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error type returned by request is an Error object:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

One of its properties is an array called properties and the second entry contains the text you see in square brackets. Javascript makes it possible to specify varying degrees of visbility and some custom objects such as Error have these properties set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties

Try running node with the `debug` switch and use `debugger` keyword to create breakpoint. i.e. Modify your code as follows:

```
if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    debugger;
}
```

Then run node as follows:

```
node debug server.js
```

1. Node will break on the first line so type 'c' to continue.
2. When it stops at the line above, type `repl` *(stands for read, eval, print, loop)* to inspect variables
   e.g. type

   `Object.keys(err)`
   to inspect properties of err (Assuming it's an object).

Fyi, for a **graphical alternative** you could try *node-inspector* which you can install with:

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

then run with

```
node-debug server.js
```

Your code will open in Chrome and give you the same tools available during front-end debugging.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks... But I still don't understand the err object... See the update to OQ

Comment: Strange. What version of node are you using? I just tried to reproduced and request gives me an error which has the keys [code, errno, syscall, address, port]

Comment: quite old. current version is 4.0.0. I know that doesn't answer your question but I was wondering why you are getting a different output. Still looking into it

Comment: ok, I see. The object type is an Error https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: I can see it in the debugger because I have a newer version of node. It is not visible because it is not iterable. The text in square brackets is the second value of the properties array child of the error object.

Comment: Thanks| Problem solved. I did never realize I was using such an old node... :-( Here @ office I'm on a Centos 6.6 (it's from 2011-2012, I suppose)...

Comment: @MarcoS: NP! I upgraded node on centos 6 only last week> sudo npm cache clean -f;sudo npm cache clean -f;sudo n stable; # and your done :)

Comment: Just did it (now I've got 4.0.0), but I always get: > `Object.keys(err) []`... :-(

Comment: @MarcoS: just check on centos 6.7. node --version => v4.0.0. Getting result I got on windows. Object.keys works for me. Are you sure correct node version is being used. e.g. try opening a new terminal

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use:

```
console.dir(err);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir

**UPDATE:**

This is a doc about Error object:

https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html

In square brackets Error shows Type and Message.
Type is error class, and message - the parameter passed to error constructor.

```
var e = new TypeError("Bla Bla Bla");
console.log(e);
```

Gives: `[TypeError: Bla Bla Bla]`